# Why are some commands are wrongly wrapped in single quotes?

Tags: bash, macos, kubectl, portforwarding

From looking at the `set -x` output it appears the 3 commands after `cut` are wrapped in single quotes. Looking at the script, they should not be; they should be preceded by the `+` operator.

This assumes a few things of course:

1. This isn't about Vault, it's about the weird Bash behavior
2. `kubectl port-forward` has executed successfully
3. Vault Has been initialized and is ready to be unsealed

***Why are these commands being wrapped in single quotes?***

Some factors:

- Occurs on macOS Mojave
- Installed/upgraded GNU Bash via Homebrew
- Using macOS Terminal

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash                                                                
# https://www.vaultproject.io

export VAULT_ADDR='http://127.0.0.1:8200'
theJelly='/tmp/jelly.out'
podVault='vault-0'

###---
### Unseal
###---
echo "Unsealing the Vault..."
set -x
unsealKey="$(grep Unseal $theJelly | cut -d' ' -f4)"
echo "$unsealKey"
kubectl exec -t "$podVault" -- vault operator unseal "$unsealKey"


vault status


######################################################################################
# OUTPUT
# Why are the commands (after cut) preceded with a single quote?
######################################################################################
$ sudo /var/tmp/vaultest.sh
Unsealing the Vault...
++ grep Unseal /tmp/jelly.out
++ cut '-d ' -f4
' unsealKey='blah=                                        # <-- why ' unsealKey=' ?
' echo 'blah=                                             # <-- why ' echo '
blah=
' kubectl exec -t vault-0 -- vault operator unseal 'blah= # <-- why ' kubectl ... '
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
+ vault status                                            # <-- then it's okay again?!
Key                Value
---                -----
Seal Type          shamir
Initialized        true
Sealed             true
Total Shares       1
Threshold          1
Unseal Progress    0/1
Unseal Nonce       n/a
Version            1.3.2
HA Enabled         false

######################################################################################
# JELLY - just an ASCII text file
######################################################################################
HOST:~ tester$ cat -vte /tmp/jelly.out 
^[[0mUnseal Key 1: blah=^[[0m^M$
^[[0m^[[0m^M$
^[[0mInitial Root Token: s.FOO^[[0m^M$
^[[0m^[[0m^M$
^[[0mVault initialized with 1 key shares and a key threshold of 1. Please securely^M$
distribute the key shares printed above. When the Vault is re-sealed,^M$
restarted, or stopped, you must supply at least 1 of these keys to unseal it^M$
before it can start servicing requests.^[[0m^M$
^[[0m^[[0m^M$
^[[0mVault does not store the generated master key. Without at least 1 key to^M$
reconstruct the master key, Vault will remain permanently sealed!^[[0m^M$
^[[0m^[[0m^M$
^[[0mIt is possible to generate new unseal keys, provided you have a quorum of^M$
existing unseal keys shares. See "vault operator rekey" for more information.^[[0m^M$
```

*If these actions (below) are done manually they totally work; eg: (minus the single quotes)*

`kubectl exec -t vault-0 -- vault operator unseal blah=`

Some diagnostic steps:

- created a new user to execute the script; user has default env vars.
- installed/upgraded iTerm2 to try something in addition to Terminal
- still got the same result with new user/terminal.
- wrote another script with similar actions (bash expansion assigned to variable)

```
# similar script
$ cat /tmp/yo.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x

yoOut='/tmp/yo.out'

yeOut="$(grep ye $yoOut | cut -d' ' -f4)"

echo "$yeOut"

# data file
$ cat /tmp/yo.out
ya
ye1 ye2 ye3 ye4
yi
yo
yu

# set -x output looks normal
$ /tmp/yo.sh
+ yoOut=/tmp/yo.out
++ grep ye /tmp/yo.out
++ cut '-d ' -f4
+ yeOut=ye4
+ echo ye4
ye4
```

This is how we would expect the output to look.

Please help, this issue is driving me bonkers.

Comment: Does `/tmp/jelly.out` have dos line endings?

Comment: @WilliamPursell, updated the `cat -vte /tmp/jelly.out` output above; there's some weird color stuff going on in there but all lines terminate with `$`.

Comment: What is "weird stuff"?  It looks like some of that may include characters that are moving the cursor around on your terminal and overwriting output.

Comment: The `^M` before the `$` is a carriage return, which indicates that the file is in DOS/Windows text format. Both this and the `^[[0m` bit (an ANSI terminal control escape sequence to set the text mode to plain) will get treated as data by the script and the programs that you pass them to (like `kubectl`). Invisible characters/sequences like this are sometimes called "gremlins", and they *will* cause trouble. You either need to remove them from the file, or write the script so that it purges them as it reads from the file.

Comment: you may need to use the for `grep --no-color srchTarg file` . Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike other languages quotes in Bash are really just a way to make some string part of a word. For example, `cut -d' '` is literally equivalent to `cut '-d '`:

```
$ echo 'foo bar' | cut '-d ' -f1
foo
```

At the point when Bash xtraces the command the quotes have already been removed, so it re-adds quotes in the simplest way possible to produce the same effect as the original command. You can go crazy with this, and still end up with the exact same command:

```
$ echo 'foo'" "'bar' | cut $'-'"d"' ' -f1
foo
```

`cut -d' '` is simply the most readable version of this command (except for `cut --delimiter=' '` IMO), which is why programmers generally write that way.

Comment: got the basics but this still leaves the unwanted characters:
`blah=^[[0m^M$`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed below; it's gross (and I hate it) but it works. [Parameter Expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion) saves the day - again. In this case:

1. Used no offset (0), and
2. Retained the first 45 characters, thereby omitting `^[[0m^M` from the end

`myVar="${myVar:0:44}"`

Now this sucks because *IF* the length of `$myVar` ever changes the script breaks.

```
...
unsealKey="$(grep Unseal $theJelly | cut -d' ' -f4)"
echo "$unsealKey"
unsealKey="${unsealKey:0:44}"                              # fixed: reassigned
kubectl exec -t "$podVault" -- vault operator unseal "$unsealKey"


vault status


######################################################################################
# OUTPUT
######################################################################################
$ sudo /var/tmp/vaultest.sh
Unsealing the Vault...
++ grep Unseal /tmp/jelly.out
++ cut '-d ' -f4
' unsealKey='blah=                                        # fail
blah=
+ unsealKey=blah=                                         # after reassignment

+ kubectl exec -t vault-0 -- vault operator unseal blah=
Key             Value
---             -----
Seal Type       shamir
Initialized     true
Sealed          false                                    # success!
...
```